# constructor not reading int[]

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, multidimensional-array

for the following code

```
    System.out.println("How many gerbils are in the lab?");
    int population = keyboard.nextInt();
    Gerbil[] gerbil = new Gerbil[population];

    gerbil = new Gerbil[population];
    int b;
    for (b = 0; b < population; b++) {
        System.out.println(b + "start");
        System.out.println("What is the id number of gerbil " + (b + 1));
        String idnumberx = keyboard.next();
        if (b == 0) {
            System.out.println(idnumberx + "0");

        } else {
            for (int c = 0; c < gerbil.length; c++) {

                if (idnumberx.equals(gerbil[c].getId())) {
                    System.out.println("Repeat, try again");
                    System.out.println(idnumberx);
                    b--;
                    System.out.println("1");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("2");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("3");

            }
            System.out.println("4");
        }
        System.out.println("5");

        System.out.println(idnumberx);


        System.out.println("What is the name for gerbil " + idnumberx);
        String nicknamex = keyboard.next();

        foodeats = new int[F];
        for (int e = 0; e < foodeats.length; e++) {
            System.out.println("how much " + food[e].foodname + " does " + nicknamex + " eat");
            int gerbileats = keyboard.nextInt();
            foodeats[e] = gerbileats;
            //if (gerbileats > maximum){
            //  {
            //System.out.println("You stoopid, try again");
            //e--;

            //else
            //  {


            //  }
            //  }
            //   }
            System.out.println(foodeats[e]);
        }


        for (int d = 0; d < population; d++) {
            System.out.println("Does " + nicknamex + " bite? Please enter True or False");
            String doesitbite = keyboard.next();
            if (doesitbite.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                bite = Boolean.parseBoolean(doesitbite);
                break;
            } else if (doesitbite.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                bite = Boolean.parseBoolean(doesitbite);
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Repeat, try again");
            d--;


        }


        for(int d = 0; d < population; d++) {
            System.out.println("Does " + nicknamex + " escape? Please enter True or False");
            String doesitescape = keyboard.next();
            if (doesitescape.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                escape = Boolean.parseBoolean(doesitescape);
                break;
            } else if (doesitescape.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                escape = Boolean.parseBoolean(doesitescape);
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Repeat, try again");
            d--;
        }


        gerbil[b] = new Gerbil(idnumberx, nicknamex, foodeats, bite, escape);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(gerbil[b]);
        for (int k = 0; k < F; k++) {
            System.out.println(foodeats[k]);
        }
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
How many gerbils are in the lab?
1
0start
What is the id number of gerbil 1
123
1230
5
123
What is the name for gerbil 123
al
how much a does al eat
2
2
how much b does al eat
2
2
Does al bite? Please enter True or False
true
Does al escape? Please enter True or False
true
0
123 al [I@d07e4bc true true
2
2
```

essentially, `[I@d07e4bc` is supposed to read out the items in foodeats[] (2,2).

below is my code for the class Gerbil containing the int[]

```
package assignment4;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Gerbil {
public int[] foodeats;
public String idnumberx;
public String nicknamex;
public String gerbilsearch;
public boolean bite;
public boolean escape;
public String foodname;
public String searchgerbil;
public int gerbileats;

public Gerbil(String idnumberx, String nicknamex, int[] foodeats, boolean bite, boolean escape) {
this.idnumberx = idnumberx; 
this.nicknamex = nicknamex; 
this.escape = escape; 
this.bite = bite; 
this.foodeats = foodeats;
}

public Gerbil(int gerbileats){
this.gerbileats = gerbileats;
}

public boolean getBite() {
return bite;
}
public boolean getEscape() {
return escape;
}
public String getId() {
return idnumberx;
}
public String getName() {
return nicknamex;
}
public void setId(String[] newId) {
idnumberx = this.idnumberx;
}
public void setName(String[] newName) {
nicknamex = this.nicknamex;
}
public int[] getFoodeats() {
return foodeats;
}

public String toString() {
return  (this.getId() + " " + this.getName() + " " + this.getFoodeats() + " " + this.getBite() + " " + this.getEscape());
}



}
```

is there anything else I need to add in order for the gerbil constructor to read the foodeats int[]?

I have a feeling that since this would result in a 2d array, id have to redefine the variables for the constructor in order to store the int array

Comment: Please just put the relevant code to your question, not everything.

Comment: That sure is a lot of code

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you print an array, you are going to get the default string for its object type.

If you want to ensure that you're getting the contents out, wrap your array with `Arrays.toString()` from the `java.util` package.  Be sure to write `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top of your program to use that class.

Since the only place it seems that you're doing that is in `toString` of `Gerbil`, you would rewrite it as this:

```
public String toString() {
    return  (this.getId() + " " + this.getName() + " "
                          + Arrays.toString(this.getFoodeats())
                          + " " + this.getBite() + " "
                          + this.getEscape());
}
```